Relationships between $\frac{\partial^2f}{{\partial}x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{{\partial}y^2}$ due to the nature of $|\mathbb{H}|_f$
$\text{ consider a continuous function of }x\text{ and }y\text{ ; }\;\;f:X\to{\mathbb{R}}^2, \;X{\subseteq}{\mathbb{R}}^2$
$\text{ with second partial derivatives that exist and are continuous,}$
$\text{ and }(a,b)\text{ is a stationary point of the function }f$;
$$\text{If }\frac{{\partial}^2f}{{\partial}x^2}(a,b)<0\text{ and }|{\mathbb{H}}|_{f,(a,b)}>0,\text{ then the point }(a,b)\text{ is a local maximum point.}$$
$$\text{If }\frac{{\partial}^2f}{{\partial}x^2}(a,b)>0\text{ and }|{\mathbb{H}}|_{f,(a,b)}>0,\text{ then the point }(a,b)\text{ is a local minimum point.}$$
$$\text{If }|{\mathbb{H}}|_{f,(a,b)}<0,\text{ then the point }(a,b)\text{ is a saddle point}$$
$$$$
This also will Intuitively hold for x being replaced with y, since the letter assigned to a variable has no effect on it's properties. Does this then not imply that $\frac{{\partial}^2f}{{\partial}x^2}(a,b)>0\;{\Rightarrow}\;\frac{{\partial}^2f}{{\partial}y^2}(a,b)>0$ and $\frac{{\partial}^2f}{{\partial}x^2}(a,b)<0\;{\Rightarrow}\;\frac{{\partial}^2f}{{\partial}y^2}(a,b)<0$ if $|\mathbb{H}|_{f,(a,b)}>0$
And further imply that  $\frac{{\partial}^2f}{{\partial}x^2}(a,b)>0\;{\Rightarrow}\;\frac{{\partial}^2f}{{\partial}y^2}(a,b)<0$ for $|\mathbb{H}|_{f,(a,b)}<0$?
$$ $$
This intuitively makes sense based on the shape of a 3D plane at each type of stationary point, but does this hold for every possible function $f$ for which the stationary point test holds?

What is $\left|\mathbb{H}\right|_f$ in your notation?

@Qphysl Hessian discriminant of f. I don't like using delta, as it has too many other uses in my opinion
